# Bash search and copy using variables

Tags: bash, search, copy, find, cp

I have a set of directories that I wish to search, ie

```
/home/*/Documents/Crashes
```

The files that I am trying to pull are of the form:

`A.log.20121022T160949Z`, where the first several numbers are the date (here 2012/10/22).

I have a text file that I pull from with usernames, read in as $line.

I only want to pull files from the current date. I've tried:

```
D= date +%Y%m%d%t
cp -ru /home/$line/Documents/Crashes/A.log.$D* /home/$USER/Documents/Todayslogs
```

and it pulls everything. Also tried find with no luck...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
D=$(date +%Y%m%d%t)
```

the `$(...)` syntax is "command substitution". In this example, it takes whatever would have been printed to stdout with `date +%Y%m%d%t` and saves it into `D`. (note: command substitution doesn't include stderr output unless you explicitly add a `2>&1`!)

Doing `D= date +%Y%m%d%t` will just print the date information to stdout without saving it to `D` like you wanted.

Comment: I made the adjustment that you mentioned. However, now 

    D=$(date +%Y%m%d%t)
    cp -ru /home/$line/Documents/Crashes/A.log.$D* /home/$USER/Documents/Todayslogs

pulls all files from /home/$USER/Documents and puts them into 
    /home/$USER/Documents/Todayslogs

Answer (score 1):

You never set the `D` variable, you only ran the date command;

```
$ D= date +%Y%m%d%t
20121026
$ echo $D
<... nadda ...>
```

Instead do:

```
$ D=$(date +%Y%m%d%t)
$ echo $D
20121026
```

Comment: What's the difference between $(xxx) and using back ticks?

Comment: @CraigWright `command` allows for backslash-escaping of `$`, back ticks and backslashes. The `$(command)` form does not.